# Getting error while sorting records in descending order by Id with orderby clause in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to display my records in descending order of my `Id` property.

But getting error below in browser console:

> [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received:
>   {"name":"Abc","EmailId":"Abc@yahoo.com","Salary":4000}

This is my code:

```
 <table>
       <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="item in User " ng-if="$odd" >
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
       <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="item in User " ng-if="$even" >
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>


             <tr ng-repeat="item in User | orderBy: '-Id'    ">
             </td>

 function Displaydata() {
        MyService.getList().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.User = data
           }, function (reason) {
      })
    }
```

Json Output:

```
    [
            {
              "Id":5,
             "name": "Abc",
             "EmailId": "Abc@yaoo.com",
             "Salary" : 4000
            },
            {
          "Id":11,
             "name": "YYY",
             "EmailId": "Abc@yaoo.com",
             "Salary" : 4000
            },
            {
              "Id":7,
             "name": "III",
             "EmailId": "Abc@yaoo.com",
             "Salary" : 4000
            },
            {'
              "Id":3,
             "name": "WWW",
             "EmailId":"Abc@yaoo.com",
             "Salary" : 4000
            }
           ]
```

Comment: It seems the problem is with your angular resource.

Comment: I tried your code in a fiddle and it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6548/

Comment: @Matheno:Actually i have 2 two on top of this code which is looping on this same object.So this can be problem??

Comment: Can you post that code also? You are probably trying to loop in a JSON object that is already 'looped' ;-)

Comment: This shouldn't make any sense: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6550/ The only thing I can think of is that `$scope.User = data` is a single object instead of an array. Like the error said.

Comment: Well, why do you have `tr` tag and closes with `td`?

Comment: I assume that it is a copy paste fault.

Comment: @Matheno:If $scope.User = data would have been single object then how i am getting 4 records in my json object

Comment: Can you do `console.log(data)` and check?

Comment: By the way, are the others (the two above) `ng-repeat` working? Also, why didn't u put the `ng-repeat` in `tr` tag instead of `td`?

Comment: @Matheno:See my answer

Comment: @developer033 :see my answer

Comment: @Chinni :I have rectify the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this assignment:

```
function Displaydata() {
        MyService.getList().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.User = data
           }, function (reason) {
      })
    }
```

Function `.then()` returns another promise object to allow chaining: `.then().then()`, and because it returns an object that's why i was receive notarray error.

To avoid this reference error you can specify $scope.User as empty arrray earlier, then assign results to it.

```
function Displaydata() {
        $scope.User = [];
        MyService.getList().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.User = data
           }, function (reason) {
      })
}
```

This worked successfully...